# Testing conference call on Android

Tags: android, sinch

I'm trying to set up a conference call using the sample app. Basically what I did was replace the

```
mSinchClient.getCallClient().callUser(userId)
```

directive with

```
mSinchClient.getCallClient().callConference(confId)
```

in the SinchService.java file. I thought that would set up a conference but it fails giving me an error:

```
com.sinch.android.rtc.sample.calling D/Call: onSessionTerminated: 94250e95-5a55-4f0f-97c0-ac85ed4f7bca: SessionDetails [startTime=1450151944, endTime=1450151946, progressTime=0, establishTime=0, terminationCause=FAILURE, packetsSent=0, packetsReceived=0, error=SinchError[errorType=OTHER, code=4000, message='DomainParameterInvalid (2228301)', data={serverCode=2228301, serverMessage=DomainParameterInvalid}]]
```

According to the documentation (https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/android/#setupaconferencecall) that's pretty much all I have to do:

```
CallClient callClient = sinchClient.getCallClient();
Call call = callClient.callConference("<conferenceId>");
call.addCallListener(...);
```

Edit:
After trying a few things here and there I got it working. The code would look something like this:

```
confToCall = etCallConf.getText().toString();
call = sinchClient.getCallClient().callConference(confToCall);
```

There's not much to it. That's probably the only difference with the sample code you get from the Sinch people.

You can find the source of my MainActivity here:
[MainActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/aLqnZnJF)

Comment: I built my own app from scratch and got the conference call to work. If anyone is interested I can show you how.

Comment: Can you please share the code?

Comment: @YasirTahir yes, I will update my question with my code

Comment: So, the userToCall should be unique? How to connect other users to the same call?

Comment: @YasirTahir yes. I actually made a mistake a mixed up the user and conf names. I'll update my post. User should be a unique identifier. If you want people to connect to the same conference they just have to share the conference name.

Comment: Kindly update your post

Answer (score 0):

If you have a conference ID set in place I would invoke the following method in order to use the Conference ID, or in this case the Call ID

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.callscreen);

    mAudioPlayer = new AudioPlayer(this);
    mCallDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.callDuration);
    mCallerName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.remoteUser);
    mCallState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.callState);
    Button endCallButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hangupButton);

    endCallButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            endCall();
        }
    });
    mCallStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mCallId = getIntent().getStringExtra(SinchService.CALL_ID);
    mPin = getIntent().getStringExtra("PIN");

}
```

Comment: I didn't have a conf ID because the conference call didn't work. I built my own app and I got it working. Thank you.