# Sinch Conference Call Android

Tags: android, sinch

I have searched about making a conference call using Sinch Android SDK but unable to find any working example. I found one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281090/testing-conference-call-on-android), but there is no solution mentioned.

According to the documentation (https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/android/#setupaconferencecall):

```
CallClient callClient = sinchClient.getCallClient();
Call call = callClient.callConference("<conferenceId>");
call.addCallListener(...);
```

My question is, If Conference ID is random then How to create Conference Room and How to add Users to that room? Is there any example or sample available for Android?

**EDIT**

I create one user with ID 1 and another user with ID 2. I call the function on button click on both of the user devices,

```
Call call = callClient.callConference("ConferenceID123");
```

As callConference will create the conference room on the fly. The call on both users get established but there is no voice completely blank on both user devices. And when I hang-up, there is 0 packet send or received. Can you please help me out where I am wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You create your own rooms and keep a list of that and then connect any users to that room.

Comment: Call call = callClient.callConference("<conferenceId>"); this code will create conference room or connect the user only?

Comment: I create one user with ID 1 and another user with ID 2. I call the function on button click on both of the user Call call = callClient.callConference("ConferenceID123"); as callConference will create the conference room on the fly. The call on both users get established but there is no voice completely blank on both user devices. And when I hang-up, there is 0 packet send or received.

Comment: CAn you mail in to support@sinch.com with callid and appkey so we can check it out?

Comment: Do you have the same problem with the sample apps? Are you asking for microphone access?

Comment: Yes I have problem with sample apps.

Comment: What kind of network are you on? You have the same problem with the app to app calling sample app?

Comment: Yes same problem with app-to-app calling sample app. I was using Wi-Fi and then I tried on 4g. Both had same results. No voice at all. Completely blank

Comment: what devices where you using?

Comment: Samsung Note 3 and Lenovo a369i

Comment: can you open a ticket with support and share your code, its usualy a error in the manifest file for microphone access, i think its some new things in marshmallow also

Comment: There is some recording util in Sinch Library. What is that for? If Sinch record the conversation, can we get that? If no, can we disable sinch recording?

Comment: The "recording " is to record from the mic and send to the other party, not record the calls the way you think about it

Comment: @cjensen how to make conference room. I did not find any of the help in documents?

Comment: @cjensen How can I get the current list of users in a particular conference call?

Comment: If one Video conference call is going on with 2 users,can i add third user to the same conference call(App to phone)? Here the third user does not have an application and will be joining the conference call through local mobile network(Audio call). Is this possible though Sinch SDK?